# How to scroll animate to specific ID minus X distance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, autoscroll

I want to scroll to a specific div then have it stop about 70px before the targeted div. Here is the tutorial I got it off:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `scrollTop: target.offset().top - 70`?

Comment: Hi @rjtkoh, it would improve your question if you mentioned what problems/error-messages you're getting --- or at least explaining what isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

substract 70 from target divs top

```
$(function() {
      $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top - 70
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          }
    }
  });
});
```